# How do I prevent IVsBuildPropertyStorage.SetItemAttribute from escaping special characters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, envdte, vsix

I am working on a Visual Studio 2010 extension and I want to add an attribute to an MSBuild Item, as follows:

```
 <EmbeddedResource Include="SomeFile.xml">
      <FooAttribute>%(Filename)%(Extension)</FooAttribute>
 </EmbeddedResource>
```

So, far the only way I found is using the method [`IVsBuildPropertyStorage.SetItemAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildpropertystorage.setitemattribute%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) . This works fine for simple strings, but when i try to use characters that are special to MSBuild, I get this result:

```
 <EmbeddedResource Include="SomeFile.xml">
      <FooAttribute>%29%25%28Filename%29%25%28Extension%29</FooAttribute>
 </EmbeddedResource>
```

This means that `SetItemAttribute` automatically escapes from MsBuild characters and I don't want that.

Comment: Are you certain that MSBuild won't accept the escaped forms of those characters?

Comment: It accept escaped form for those characters... BUT i don't want to escape i want "%(Filename)%(Extension)" in my project file. If i let "%29%25%28Filename%29%25%28Extension%29" msbuild will take  this like as a string constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but needs an answer. VS2010 seems to have better interface that can set values without escaping.

> **IVsBuildPropertyStorage2 Interface**
>
> Implemented by the project system to give flavors access to the
>   MSBuild property system. This interface provides more flexibility
>   around setting properties than IVsBuildPropertyStorage. It allows for
>   adding a new conditional property group and **does not escape the
>   values.**

Namely the function **SetPropertyValueEx**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildpropertystorage2.setpropertyvalueex.aspx

Comment: The documentation is not correct (not your fault). You are actually looking for the [`IVsBuildPropertyStorage2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildpropertystorage2.aspx) interface, which added the [`SetPropertyValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildpropertystorage2.setpropertyvalueex.aspx) method starting in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Ah thanks, I knew something fishy was going on, though, I noticed that this is SetPropertyValue, not SetItemAttribute. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: To be honest, it is so old that I completely forgot what I was doing, I'm no longer in .Net land. But better later than never :)

Comment: @SamHarwell How do you actually get an `IVsBuildPropertyStorage2`? I can cast an `IHierarchy` to an `IVsBuildPropertyStorage`, but I can't cast 
 it to an `IVsBuildPropertyStorage2`.